# Why is MESSAGE_OUTBOUND_PROPERTY in handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext context) always true?

Tags: web-services, soap

I am writing a SoapHandler to intercept SOAP calls.  I'm testing whether its an incoming or outgoing soap message as follows:

```
public class MySoapHandler implements SOAPHandler<SOAPMessageContext> {
    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MySoapHandler.class);

    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext context) {
        Boolean isRequest = (Boolean) context.get(MessageContext.MESSAGE_OUTBOUND_PROPERTY);

if(isRequest)logger.debug("isRequest=true");
else logger.debug("isRequest=false");
```

When I submit the soap request I see "isRequest=true" occur twice, first when the soap request is received, and then again just before the soap response is sent.  I was expecting to see "isRequest=false" the second time.

Can anyone shed some light?

Comment: I think I know why.  If you look at actual message it is MESSAGE_OUTBOUND_PROPERTY=true and MESSAGE_OUTBOUND_PROPERTY=false.  Casting to Boolean will produce true in both cases.

Comment: actually that wasn't quite right either.  MessageContext.MESSAGE_OUTBOUND_PROPERTY is of type boolean.  context.get of type Object.  So above should work, unless isRequest should be of type boolean, not Boolean

Comment: yes, that was it.  here is what works:        boolean isResponse = (Boolean)context.get(MessageContext.MESSAGE_OUTBOUND_PROPERTY);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boolean needs to be boolean:

```
public class MySoapHandler implements SOAPHandler<SOAPMessageContext> {
    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MySoapHandler.class);

    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext context) {
        boolean isRequest = (Boolean) context.get(MessageContext.MESSAGE_OUTBOUND_PROPERTY);

if(isRequest)logger.debug("isRequest=true");
else logger.debug("isRequest=false");
```